# What happens when I get fainted after accomplishing the main objective?

Tags: monster-hunter-world

Last time when I went to the Rotten Vale, a stray Baselgeuse came to my location and nearly found me right after I have slain the main target. Fortunately, I managed to get undetected, but this led me to the following question.

What happens when I get fainted while I'm on the return timer? Is it considered as being fainted during the quest and drops my reward or screws the quest? If not, to where do I get carried? Do I land on the nearest camp and the return timer still ticks? Or, do I skip the timer and go to the chosen destination?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't faint when you complete your primary objective. Once you get the cutscene, you are invulnerable; fire won't damage you, attacks won't hurt, nothing will.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, one of the more recent content updates made it so that you couldn't be interrupted while carving post-completion.

Comment: @Fluttershy good, finally... That was super annoying in the past games